# How to updated ListView 2 based on Item clicked on ListView 1

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new to MVC and PyQt programming. I wanted to figure out way to update ListView on clicking an item from another ListView. I am going by MVC.

ListView 1 is updated by listing all the primary nodes of XML file. 
ListView 2 should be updated with child nodes of the clicked parent node from ListView 1.

How can I emit signal from ListView1 (onClicked()) and capture in ListView2 along with proper Item that was clicked. Once I have this Item, I can use it with existing logic to populate ListView2 using this Item.

Till now I have tried different approach but none worked. Including:

```
val = ListView1.clicked.connect(getRowName)

def getRowName():
    data = ListView1.selectedIndexes()
    print(data)
    return data
```

"data" variable isnt holding any value even after clicking on item in ListView1.

One more thing, Do I have to consider two model one each for ListView 1 and ListView 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using `QListWidgets` and `QListWidgetItems`.  `QListWidgets` have an `itemSelectionChanged` signal.

```
listwidget1 = QListWidget(self)
listwidget2 - QListWidget(self)
listwidget1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(function_that_updates_listwidget2)
```

If you are set on using `QListView`, you can subclass `QListView` and override the [`selectionChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistview.html#selectionChanged) method, which is called whenever the selection is changed.  You could either do the update on list 2 directly in that callback, or have it emit a custom signal similar to `QListWidget`, and then handle the signal using the list2 update function.

```
class MyList(QListView):

    itemSelectionChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        super(MyList, self).selectionChanged(selected, deselected)
        self.itemSelectionChanged.emit()
```

Yes, if each listview is showing different data, then you will need to use separate models.

Comment: I am sorrry if I have confused you, but in my query I should have used Clicked instead of Selected. So I am trying to figure out way to retrieve item (that was clicked in ListView1) along with signal, using which I can updated content in ListView2. BTW Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why must it be on click as opposed to selection?  Is that what you really want?  If you're updating the second list based off the selection in the first list, you only want to update when the selection changes, right?  If you use `clicked`, it will update the second list *every* time a click is registered in the first list, even if nothing is selected and even if the selection doesn't change.

Comment: But how will I pass information on which ITEM in the list was selected? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to pass that information.  In your refresh function for list2 you can use `list1.selectedItems()` (if using QListWidget) or `list1.selectedIndexes()` (if using QListView) to get the selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brendan, I got it !!